# UIImageView and CGRectIntersectRect (Xcode)

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimageview

I have 2 `UIImageViews` whose sizes are 50x50 and 60x60 pixel.

I use `CGRectIntersectRect` method to determine when one image touches the other. But these 2 images are 2 balls and sometimes code determines that these images are touching themselves when "with your eyes" you can see they don't touch. This happens because balls don't "cover" all spaces of image. So the corners of images are clear, but of course code doesn't care about this.

The question is: how can I solve? how can I determine the frame of images that follow perfectly the circumference of balls?

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure that the image in the `UIImageView`s will always be circles (or the `UIImageView`s will always be square), then you can do something like

```
CGRect frame1 = image1.frame;
CGRect frame2 = image2.frame;
CGPoint center1 = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(frame1), CGRectGetMidY(frame1));
CGPoint center2 = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(frame2), CGRectGetMidY(frame2));

CGFloat dx = center1.x - center2.x;
CGFloat dy = center2.x - center2.y;
float squaredDistance = dx * dx + dy * dy;

CGFloat radius1 = frame1.size.width/2;
CGFloat radius2 = frame2.size.width/2;
CGFloat minDistance = radius1 + radius2;
if (squaredDistance <= minDistance * minDistance) {
    //Intersect
} else {
    //Do not intersect
}
```

I tried to make everything parametric but, of course, if `UIImageView`'s frames are fixed then you can write a simpler code using, for example, `#define` directives.

For example, if you know that the first image is 50x50 and the second is 60x60 you can write something like

```
#define RADIUS1 25
#define RADIUS2 30
```

and simplify your code.

I assumed that each circle is inscribed in the `UIImageView`'s frame. If not, then you should know the exact ratio to measure the radius correctly. (By far it's easier to have the circles inscribed in the frames.)